# How can I create a re-usable piece of markup in Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, view, express, pug

### What I'm trying to accomplish.

What I'm trying to do is actually really simple and the Jade template engine should be able to help me out quite a bit with it, but I'm running into some snags.

I'm building a site that uses a lot of semi-transparent elements like the one in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Chevex/UfKnM/
In order to make the container background be semi-transparent but keep the text opaque this involves 3 elements:

- A container DIV with `position: relative`
- A child DIV with `position: absolute`, a background color, height/width set to 100%, and its opacity set to the desired level.
- Another child DIV for the content with no special positioning.

It's pretty simple and I use it fairly effectively on [CodeTunnel.com](http://www.codetunnel.com).

### How I want to simplify it.

I'm re-writing CodeTunnel.com in node.js and the Jade template engine seems like it could greatly simplify this piece of markup that I re-use over and over again. Jade mixins look promising so here's what I did:

1. I defined a mixin so I could just use it wherever I need it.

   ```
   mixin container
       .container(id=attributes.id) // attributes is an implicit argument that contains any attributes passed in.
           .translucentFrame
           .contentFrame
               block // block is an implicit argument that contains all content from the block passed into the mixin.
   ```
2. Use the mixin, passing in a block of content:

   ```
   +container#myContainer
       h1 Some test content
   ```

   Generates:

   ```
   <div id="myContainer" class="container">
       <div class="translucentFrame"></div>
       <div class="contentFrame">
           <h1>Some test content</h1>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

So far everything works great! There is just one problem. I want to use this mixin in a layout.jade template and I want the child template to be able to use block inheritance. My layout.jade file looks like this:

```
doctype 5
mixin container
    .container(id=attributes.id)
        .translucentFrame
        .contentFrame
            block
html
    head
        title Container mixin text
    body
        +container#bodyContent
            block bodyContent
```

Then in another jade file (index.jade) I extend layout.jade:

```
extends layout

block bodyContent
    h1 Some test Content
```

Everything looks to be in order but the jade parser fails:

[image]

I assume it has something to do with the `block` keyword conflicting. Inside a mixin `block` is an implicit argument containing the block passed into the mixin, but when extending a jade template block is a keyword that identifies a block of markup that is to be substituted in the equivalent block in the parent template.

If I replace the `block bodyContent` that I'm passing into the mixin with any other markup then everything works fine. It's only when I try to pass in a block definition that it gets upset.

Any ideas?

Comment: Has anything changed since you originally posted this? i.e. does this work now, or is there a better approach ?

Comment: @CodeBling I don't believe much has changed here.

Comment: That's too bad. Seems like something that will be solved in Jade 2, which [should be released soonish](https://github.com/jadejs/jade/milestones).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suspect that, because [mixins define their own functions](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a14), the `block bodyContent` is being defined in different scope inaccessible from `index.jade`.

What you can try instead is to move the use of the mixin to the inheriting view since [mixins are "hoisted"](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/pull/624):

`layout.jade`:

```
doctype 5

mixin container
    .container(id=attributes.id)
        .translucentFrame
        .contentFrame
            block

html
    head
        title Container mixin text
    body
        block bodyContent
```

`index.jade`:

```
extends layout

block bodyContent
    +container#myContainer
        h1 Some test content
```

Comment: Yeah I can do that, I just then have to use the mixin on every single inheriting view because I want every view's bodyContent to be wrapped in this container. I suppose it's not that big of a deal. I could just manually create the elements (without the mixin) for use in the layout view and then use the mixin everywhere else.